# How to match a space using Regex in Python

Tags: python, regex

How come the code below is not matching the space character?

```
import re

hasSpace = re.compile(' ')

string = 'hello world'

if(hasSpace.match(string)):
    print("Found a space")
else:
    print("No space")
```

I also tried using:

```
hasSpace = re.compile('\s')
```

but it's not matching either. I also tried to add an **r** to make the string raw, but same result.

Any clue why?

Comment: see the match function doc, match tries to match from the start. Since there isn't a space char at the start, it fails.

Comment: Why would you use Regex for this?  `if ' ' in string:` is all you need.

Comment: @iCodez the pattern is more complex, but I need to be able to match the space first.

Comment: Replace `match` by `search`

Comment: @AvinashRaj you are correct. The problem is the match function. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `match` by search:

```
>>> if(hasSpace.search(string)):
...      print("Found a space")
... else:
...     print("No space")
...
Found a space
```

Comment: Thanks. Will pick your answer once time allows.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use the `search` method. `search` ["scans through a string, looking for any location where this RE matches."](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#performing-matches)

```
import re

hasSpace = re.compile(' ')

string = 'hello world'

if(hasSpace.search(string)):
    print("Found a space") # gets printed
else:
    print("No space")

string = 'helloworld'

if(hasSpace.search(string)):
    print("Found a space")
else:
    print("No space") # gets printed
```

What you were trying to use is `match`, which ["determines if the RE matches at the beginning of the string."](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#performing-matches)

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to get to the answer using match then you can do it this way (not recommended.)
since match starts from the beginning you will need to match the 5 letters of the word 'hello' with '.....' and then match the space

```
import re
hasSpace = re.compile('..... ')
string = 'hello world'
if(hasSpace.match(string)):
  print("Found a space")
else:
  print("No space")
```

**output**

```
Found a space
```